# How to write nested SpEL expression in XML

Tags: xml, spring, spring-el

I am trying to use SpEL expression like below but not working.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/myurl" 
     access="#{'${perm.status}' == 'secured' ? 'T(XXX.YYY.PermissionsConstants).PERMISSION_NAME' : 
            'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'}"/>
```

If I replace `T(XXX.YYY.PermissionsConstants).PERMISSION_NAME` with constant like `VIEW_PERM` then it is working. Everything else is working fine except constant part. I tried with `#{T(XXX.YYY.PermissionsConstants).PERMISSION_NAME}` also but no luck.

Please suggest me correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write SpEL like `#{expression}`.

In your case it should be like

```
<intercept-url pattern="/myurl" 
     access="#{'${perm.status}' == 'secured' ? T(XXX.YYY.PermissionsConstants).PERMISSION_NAME : 
            'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'}"/>
```

Don't wrap `T(XXX.YYY.PermissionsConstants).PERMISSION_NAME` with quotes, while `'${perm.status}'` or any `String` needs to be wrapped with quotes.

Suppose that you need to write the same expression in java class then you would be writing it like:

```
@Value("${perm.status}")
String permStatus;

// Inside a method
String expressionValue =  == permStatus == "secured" ? PermissionsConstants.PERMISSION_NAME : "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY";
```

Similarly, you need to write it inside `#{}` with some changes:

1. Replace double quotes with single quotes
2. Class name should be replaced with fully qualified class name
3. Wrap fully qualified class name with `T()` before accessing any constant from the class.

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: I tried java approach, I did not try nested which looks complex.